# Spark flatten dataset mapped col

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with schema -

```
Schema: {
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ 

 {
    "name" : "cola",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "mappedcol",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "keyType" : "string",
      "valueType" : "string",
      "valueContainsNull" : true
    },
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "colc",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }]
  }
```

Sample value:

```
{
cola : A1,
mappedcol : { mapped1: M1, mapped2: M2, mapped3: M3  }
colc : C1
}
```

I want to pull the keys in mappedcols up one level. Basically flatten all the columns at one level.

```
cola, mapped1, mapped2, mapped3, colc
A1, M1,M2,M3, C1
```

Is there an elegant way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to access the single elements of the nested structure with a dot syntax, e.g. `select mappedcol.mapped1` would return `M1`. The idea is to transform the schema into a list of column names using this dot syntax:

```java
private static List<String> structToColNames(StructField[] fields, String prefix) {
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    for( StructField field: fields) {
        String fieldname = field.name();
        if( field.dataType() instanceof StructType) {
            columns.addAll(
                structToColNames(((StructType)field.dataType()).fields(), 
                    prefix + fieldname + "."));
        }
        else {
            columns.add(prefix + fieldname);
        }
    }
    return columns;
}
```

The result of this function can then be used to select the data:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(<path to json>);
StructField[] fields = df.schema().fields();
List<String> colNames = structToColNames(fields, "");
System.out.println(colNames);
Column[] columns = colNames.stream().map(s -> col(s)).toArray(Column[]::new);
df.select(columns).show();
```

prints

```
[cola, colc, mappedcol.mapped1, mappedcol.mapped2, mappedcol.mapped3]

+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
|cola|colc|mapped1|mapped2|mapped3|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  A1|  C1|     M1|     M2|     M3|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
```